# How to get first element map from an array using clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have an array of result `({:a one})`. I want a result which returns one when I select or give `:a`.

I used `vals,get-in` functions but since the map is inside a list they are not working. Can you please help me how do I do that.

I need to return value for a given key.

Also,

What if the data is of the form

```
({:a “Favorite fruit", :measurements [{:a “fav game?", :b "x",
:name “foot ball", :max 7.0, :min 0.0, :id “12345"}], :name “Frequency”})
```

and I want to select `:a "fav game?"` `:name "foot ball"` and `:min 0.0` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### List comprehension

List comprehension using [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) with any quantity of elements in the list:

```
(for [x data :let [m (:measurements x)]] (map #(let [{:keys [a name min]} %] [a name min]) m))
```

Details:

- `for [x data` for every element in data
- `:let [m (:measurements x)]]` set `m` as a symbol for `:measurements`
- `(map #(let [{:keys [a name min]} %] [a name min]) m)` for every `m` get the keys `a name min` and output a vector `[a name min]`.

Output:

```
((["fav name?" "foot ball" 0.0]))
```

### Or one result

Directly using [apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply):

```
(let [{:keys [a name min]} (apply (comp first :measurements) data)] [a name min])
```

Details:

- `(apply (comp first :measurements) data)` apply `comp`osition, first get `:measurements` then the `first` elem.
- `let [{:keys [a name min]}` get the keys `a name min` from the map and output a vector `[a name min]`.

Output:

```
["fav name?" "foot ball" 0.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much... This was really helpful and easily understood for starters like me.

Comment: If you have lots of these nested operations, a library like [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) or functional lenses might be helpful too. They make nested Clojure code much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
clj.core=> (def data [ {:a 1} {:b 2} ] )
#'clj.core/data
clj.core=> (:a (first data))
1
clj.core=> (mapv :a data)
[1 nil]
```

Comment: Not sure if your sequence has more than one map like `data` above. Post additional example if I'm missing something.

Comment: What if the data is of the form ({:a “Favorite fruit", :measurements [{:a “fav game?", :b "x", :name “foot ball", :max 7.0, :min 0.0, :id “12345"}], :name “Frequency”}) and I want to select -:a "fav :name "football" and :min 0.0 ?

Comment: No, The data exactly looks like this  ({:a “Favorite fruit", :measurements [{:a “fav game?", :b "x", :name “foot ball", :max 7.0, :min 0.0, :id “12345"}], :name “Frequency”})

Comment: And what should the output be?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a vector of results (usually more idiomatic than a list), you can use get in, but with numbers as keys. e.g.

```
(get-in [{:a "one"}] [0 :a])  ;=> "one"
```

Comment: I actually used (map (juxt :a)(into [] ({:a "one"})))

Comment: Can you help with the next continued question which I just added

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `juxt` in that case; do you want a nested vector?

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Marcs answer (and for some extra Clojure help) there are a few ways to pull values out using [destructuring](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) too.

Starting with the example you gave

```
(def foobar
  {:a "Favorite fruit", :measurements [{:a "fav game?", :b "x",
   :name "foot ball", :max 7.0, :min 0.0, :id "12345"}], :name "Frequency"})
```

We can do associative destructuring since Clojure maps are associative data structures

```
;; associative destructuring
(let [{:keys [a]} foobar]
  a)

;; also associative destructuring in the function params this time
((fn [{:keys [a]}]
   a)
 foobar)
```

To a get single value out of a map wrapped in an array we can use a combination of sequential and associative destructuring

```
(let [[{:keys [a]}] '({:a 'one})]
  a)
```

For the last part you asked about with getting `:a :name :min` we can use another destructuring combo

```
(let [{a :a [{min :min}] :measurements name :name} foobar]
  [a name min])
```

That clojure.org article I linked to is pretty awesome for explaining more details!